# In Lattice Cryptography, why is it hard to find short vectors if given long vectors?

Tags: lattice-crypto

In lattice cryptography it seems like giving out long vectors for a lattice that can be drawn from much shorter vectors (generating an identical lattice) is somehow useful for public-private key schemes and similar. Why exactly is it hard to find short vectors if given long vectors, can't the lattice just be generated and then the shorter vectors discovered super easily?

Comment: From wiki; Ajtai showed that the SVP problem was **NP-hard**, and The time complexity of known algorithms that find the exact solution are at least exponential in the dimension of the lattice.

Comment: The proof is based on reduction to [Exact Set Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) which is known to be NP-complete, see the lecture notes of [Vaikuntanathan](https://people.csail.mit.edu/vinodv/6876-Fall2015/L10.pdf)

Comment: Why is it exponential in the dimension the lattice is in? Are the long vectors like.... super long? So long that for it to begin to draw the pattern of the shortest vector, you would have to plot a lot of points?

Comment: In all visualizations the long vectors are just... twice the length of the shortest one, so if you plot those you only need a couple of them for the shortest one to appear

Comment: You just thinking in two dimension. $2^2 =4 $, consider $n$ dimension $2^n$

Comment: Yes I know, but even in 2^n if the longest vector is just the second longest, it is quite easy to plot a couple (in n dimensions) and then see the shortest vector, isn't it? Does it get harder to find the shortest vector the longer the long vector is?

Comment: @oRinga You cannot just "plot" a 100-dimensional lattice and "see" which vectors are the shortest. And no, the hardness does not necessarily come from the given vectors being very very long, but from the dimension increasing. In any case, SVP is considered "hard" similar to how factoring for RSA is considered "hard", mostly because we have no idea how to solve these problems quickly. Maybe tomorrow someone finds a way to factor RSA moduli and everyone will think "doh!" but given that many smart people have attempted and failed, it just seems unlikely.